# Share API button for iPhone

Tags: ios, facebook, twitter, share

I want to integrate a "share" button that syncs:

- With Facebook
- With Twitter
- With mail
- With LinkedIn
- With ...

I can integrate all of this by myself but maybe already exists a library that does all.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

Try `ShareKit`?

Comment: Is there any other option other than sharekit.

Comment: "Reinventing the wheel"? Why?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try:

https://www.addthis.com/

Don't forget replace your API Keys.